# How to print Unique Employee name and there Leaves

Tags: php, mysqli

in a table

Empname...    LeaveType .....    Duration

1@  ....        Unplanned ....   Full Day

2@  ....         planned...     .Half Day

1@ ....         Planned   ....   Half Day

2@  ....        Unplanned ...   Full Day
.
.
.

Question this table come from mysql DB 
and you have to print unique employee name and there leave count like Planned leave2 ubplanned leave 2 .

and if leave if Full day then Count as 1 and if Half Day then count as .5 and Show that you have take 2.5 (Two and Half day leave) in Month

In PHP...
thanks in advance...

```
<?php
include("Db_conection.php");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query="SELECT emp_email as Emp_Email,
    SUBSTRING(leave_date, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(leave_date) - 8) AS Leave_Date, leave_type as Leave_type, leave_type2 as Reason, leave_type3 as Duration, Addedby
    FROM employee_attendance WHERE MONTH(leave_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$query); 


    //$count= mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $i=0;
    $emp_email= array();
    $planned  = array();
    $unplanned= array();
    $Duration = array();
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           $k=1;
           $l=1;
           $m=1;
                        if (!in_array($row['Emp_Email'], $emp_email)) { 
                            $emp_email[$i] = $row['Emp_Email'];
                            if($row['Leave_type']=='Unplanned Leave'){
                            $unplanned[$i] = 1;

                            } 
                            if($row['Leave_type']=='Planned Leave'){
                            $planned[$i] = 1;
                            }
                            if($row['Duration']=='Full Day'){
                            $Duration[$i]=1;
                            }else{
                            $Duration[$i]=.5;
                            }

                    }
                    else{

                    $key=array_search($row['Emp_Email'], $emp_email);
                            if($row['Leave_type']=='Unplanned Leave'){
                            $k= $k+1;
                            $unplanned[$key] = $k;
                    }
                    if($row['Leave_type']=='Planned Leave'){
                            $l= $l+1;
                            $planned[$key] = $l;
                    }
                    if($row['Duration']=='Full Day'){
                            $m= $m+1;
                            $Duration[$key] = $m;
                    }else{

                            $m=$m+.5;
                            $Duration[$key] = $m;
                    }
                    }
                    $i++;
}

echo "<table border='1' align='center'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='10'>
            <tr background:red colspan='2'>
            <th bgcolor='#Green'>Emp_Email</th>
            <th bgcolor='#CCCC99'>Total Days In Month</th>
            <th bgcolor='#CCCC99'>Planned</th>
            <th bgcolor='#CCCC99'>Unplanned</th>
            <th bgcolor='#CCCC99'>Tolal Leaves</th>
            <th bgcolor='#CCCC99'>Total Days Work</th>
            </tr>";
            $j;
for($j =0; $j<9; $j++){
            if($emp_email[$j]=="")
            continue;
        echo "<tr color='grey'>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . $emp_email[$j] . "</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . '31' . "</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . $planned[$j] . "</td>";

            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . $unplanned[$j] . "</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . $Duration[$j] . "</td>";
            echo "<td bgcolor='White'>" . (31-($Duration[$j] )) . "</td>";      
            echo "</tr>";
            }
        echo "</table>";
        print_r($emp_email);

    mysqli_close($dbcon);
   ?>
```

wrote this code but there is a loophole that its showing 
    Undefined offset: 7 in  error...
    Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 76

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 77

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 78

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 74

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 76

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 74

Notice: Undefined offset: 7 in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\index4.php on line 76



Not printing one blank value also...
not updating when leaves value is more then two ...
```

Comment: are these data come from single table or multiple table as you can get expected result using SQL

Answer (score 1):

SQL solution : Try something like this(if I understood you correctly)

```
SELECT t.Empname,t.LeaveType,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.Duration = 'Half Day' THEN 0.5 ELSE 1.0 END) as leaf_count
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.Empname,t.leaveType
```